# Mac Mail sent messages not in sent folder

Tags: macos, apple-mail, g4, powerbook

My PowerBook G4 has been lobbying for a furlough recently, and its latest prank is to not show sent messages in my sent mailbox. I have always had a copy of every sent message, and now, for some unknown reason, I can only see sent messages from May 7 and earlier.

When I did a test, and sent myself an email, it shows up fine in my inbox, but there's nothing in the sent folder. Weird. It also has the little arrow next to messages that I replied to in the inbox. I guess I'm going to have to cc myself on everything until I get this fixed.

Also, it's got another new trick, which I'm assuming is unrelated, but I mention it here just in case it is: the battery says it's "good" and has a cycle count of 0, and a full charge capacity of 2139, but for some reason it's all of a sudden not charging when it's plugged in. It works fine when connected to the wall, but there is no battery life at all. Zip.

Any thoughts? Is it just time for a new 'book? This one just got back from Apple, having its harddrive replaced for the fourth time (for free, but seriously, this thing is a lemon).

Answer (score 2):

Mac's mail could have failed, it could also mean that your Mail provider could have something to deal with it too. A simple way to fix that is make sure you redefine which folder is your "sent" mail folder.

Here's a good guide I found on Google to do so:
http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/230/Apple+Mail+(Mail.app)+not+saving+to+Sent+folder

Now for the battery issue, there is a known issue to older batteries to have randomly stop charging. It is usually the battery's issue, but it could also have been an issue with your PMU (power management unit). You may want to consult this page: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379

If it is the battery, you can try to replace it under "non-warranty, known issues", but that program may have expired a while ago. Batteries for that device could range to about $100.

It is totally up to you if you want to get a new Macbook, especially the aluminum series. Better processor, capabilities, and Snow Leopard support. Getting a new one is expensive, but you can't really go wrong with it.